# rogue process? sourceforge.net in processes :S

Tags: macos, security

Weird, I found this in activity monitor, seems strange...

any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari starts a process for each tab: the processes are named with the URL you are visiting.

To have an overview sort the process hierarchically: you will see that these processes are owned by Safari:

[image: View Menu]

For example:

[image: Example with Safari sub-processes]

Comment: I don't have safari open.

Comment: Are you sure? Which is the parent process of 545?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't have safari open in last two years. And now process disappeared :S

Comment: I can happen that a child process survives the parent process but it an error. In any case the process you saw is nothing to worry about. If Safari is closed and the process is still there you can safely kill it.